# Strange. Asterisk key plays random Windows sound when pressed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, system-sounds

This is a new one on me.
When I press the "asterisk", or * button on my number pad (but not SHIFT+8), Windows makes either a "Exclamation" or "Windows ding" sound. I haven't noticed a pattern to which sound is made.

Logitech K200 keyboard
No special key mapping software or Logitech software running
Realtek sound to stereo through optical cable.
Visual Studio 2010, Chrome, Fiddler, WinRAR, Notepad++, and Dropbox running.

No unusual behavior otherwise.

A solution isn't terribly important but my curiosity is both piqued and stumped. This doesn't normally happen and nothing odd has taken place otherwise.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

- Use [ShortcutsMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html) to see if you have a hotkey assigned to the asterisk key.
- Try the same thing with [ActiveHotkeys](http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/). This looks at a different thing to ShortcutsMan I think. But unfortunately it only runs on 32bit machines.
- Try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see if anything unusual happens when you press the asterisk key. Maybe try a filter of "Operation is Process Start" to start with.